# What is the exact difference between "git push -u" and "git push --set-upstream"?

Tags: git, git-push

**Scenario 1**:
When we create a remote repo and then try to push to GitHub, we must do `git push -u repoName branchName`.

**Scenario 2**:
When we create a new branch locally and then we push to GitHub, we must do `git push --set-upstream repoName BranchName`.

So, my question is: Is there any difference between `git push -u` and `git push --set-upstream`?

If yes, what is exactly the difference?

Comment: No difference, it's the same flag. `git push --help`

Comment: The difference: just `--set` and `pstream`. (I'll show myself out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is **NO** difference between `git push -u` and `git push --set-upstream`. Git options `-u` and `--set-upstream` are the same.

Please check [`git push -u` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--u) or just type `git push --help` in the command line for more information.