# Is there any difference between "-u" and "--set-upstream" for the "git push" command?

Tags: git, git-push

Can someone please explain the difference, if it exists, between both commands:

1. `git push --set-upstream origin master`
2. `git push -u origin master`

I tested both and both push but I am unable to see the difference between them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53410553/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/71272544/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+difference+%22-u%22+%22--set-upstream%22

Comment: You can easily check, for any git command, its documentation by typing `git help <cmd>` in a terminal.  For example, the main answer is an excerpt from `git help push`. This is the goto method to check if a command supports a specific flag, or how it should be worded, or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the exact same command. `-u` and `--set-upstream` are different names for the same flag.

Quoting the docs for [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u):

> `-u`, `--set-upstream` 
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less `git-pull` and other commands. For more information, see `branch.<name>.merge` in `git-config`.

Do note that setting an upstream for the `master` branch is entirely optional. You can  omit `-u`/`--set-upstream` entirely if you don't plan on using the argument-less variants of `git push`/`git pull`/etc. See [What is a git upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17122245/11082165) and [Definition of "downstream" and "upstream"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2739376/11082165) for more information on what setting an "upstream" means in git.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between ‘git push –set-upstream origin master’ and ‘git push –u origin master’. The ‘-u’ option is a shorthand for ‘—set-upstream’. Both commands will accomplish the task of pushing changes to the remote repository and setting up tracking for the specified branch. The use of -u is just a shorter and more convenient way to specify --set-upstream.